# Is $n\ \log_2\left(n\right)\ ∈\ Ω\left(n^{1.001}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am trying to find out what class of function is this $n^{1.001}$ as I need to know whether it will smaller or equal to $n\ \log_2\left(n\right)$ . I am using master theorem where i am trying sigma = 0.001 for case 3

Comment: What's $\Omega$? Also, $\log(n)$ is $\mathcal O(n^k)$ for every $k>0$.

Comment: it is Big Omega

Comment: It is clear that $\Omega$ is capital Omega, but what does it mean here?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt wikipedia has an [explanation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations). This notation/terminology is standard in the discussion of computer algorithms and computational complexity.

Comment: Its the same as $n\ \log_2\left(n\right)\ \ge n^{1.001}$ asymptotically

Comment: @NigelNg the answer to your question is no.  It suffices to note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log_2 n}{n^{1.001}} = 0.
$$
More generally, we will always have $\log_2(n) = O(n^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is right.  Nigel should know the definition of $\Omega$ and apply it as Omno has done.  Then in the future Nigel will not have to ask us.

Comment: I see then. Thanks :-P @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, if only everybody would just figure out the answers to their own questions, they wouldn't have to ask us anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, $\log(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$. (The base of $\log$ doesn't matter, because logarithms with different bases are scalar multiples of each other.) The proof is by L'Hôpital: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dn} \log n}{\frac{d}{dn} n^\epsilon} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{-1}}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon - 1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon n^\epsilon} = 0.$$
As an immediate consequence, $n \log n = o(n^{1.001})$, and the statement in your title is false.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof that
$\log(n) = o(n^c)$
for any $c > 0$.

If $n > 1$ and $0 < c < 1$,
 then

$\begin{array}\\
\log(n)
&=\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t^{1-c}}\\
&=\dfrac{t^c}{c}|_1^n\\
&=\dfrac{n^c-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{n^c}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $c/2$ for $c$,
$\log(n)
\lt \dfrac{n^{c/2}}{c/2}
$
so
$\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^c}
\lt \dfrac{2}{cn^{c/2}}
\to 0
$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is equivalent to

$$\log n\stackrel?\in\Omega(n^{0.001}),$$

and in fact the particular exponent is irrelevant. Indeed, using $n:=m^{1000a}$ with $a>0$, the proposition becomes

$$1000a\log m\stackrel?\in\Omega(m^{a}),$$ or just

$$\log m\stackrel?\in\Omega(m^{a})$$ and the logarithm grows slower than any positive power.

But we can take for granted that

$$\log m\notin\Omega(m).$$